# Is it possible to make yoghurt at home with dairy-free milks (soy, coconut, etc)?

Tags: yogurt, dairy-free

I regularly make my own yoghurt from cow's milk by adding live yoghurt and leaving it to incubate for a few hours.  Is it possible to make dairy free yoghurt (from soy milk, or coconut milk, or other dairy free milk alternatives?)  I know it is available to buy in the shops but what would the process be for making it at home?

Comment: There are tons of recipes for "homemade soy yogurt". Just search the web...

Comment: Although I cannot speak with too much authority, I do know that in general, the less fat yogurt is made with, the more sugar is added to make it palatable. Here are a couple of references:
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/womens-health/10563265/Theres-HOW-MUCH-sugar-in-a-low-fat-yoghurt-Skirting-the-Issue.html
http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/6-dangerous-foods-in-disguise.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  You just have to use a culture that can be used on vegetable milks.  The method is basically the same as with regular yogurt.

Comment: To improve your answer, could you perhaps explain what is different about the cultures that work on vegetable milks from the "normal" cultures? Perhaps describe if they're more difficult to find or if they are likely the cultures that the OP may already be using.